# Existence/Uniqueness of solution of singular ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the following singular ODE
$$
(t^{N-1}g(y'))'=t^{N-1}f(y)
$$
with initial condition
$$y(0)=y_0$$
$$y'(0)=0$$.
where $g$ is and increasing function.
How one can prove that this problem has a solution?

Comment: Why do you believe it has one?

Comment: It is difficult to understand both variables and functions, please, define them. In any case, it looks like homework.

Comment: $g$ and $f$ are increasing function. $t$ is the variable and $y$ the unknown function.


Comment: @mikitov's theory that this is homework is still not disproved. Voting to close until it is...

Comment: In many papers about blow-up of solution of non linear PDE's the existence of radially symmetric solution is given for granted without any further comment. 
I am trying to understand this fact. 
The previous equation is a toy model for this.
Thank you for your help.


Comment: Ah, OK. You might get better responses if you add this explanation to your question.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable?  If so, are you assuming that $g'(0)>0$?  Are you worried about local solutions near $t=0$ or do you only care about global solutions defined for all $t$?

Answer (score 4):

One cannot prove existence in the generality that you have stated it.  For example, if $g(p) = e^p$, there is no solution when $N>1$ and $f$ is differentiable.

To see this, observe that, if there were a solution $y(t)$ to your problem in a neighborhood of $t=0$, then the curve $(t,y,p) = (t,y(t),y'(t))$ would be an integral curve of the system
$$
dy - p\ dt = d(t^{N-1}g(p)) - t^{N-1}f(y)\ dt = 0
$$ 
that passes through the point $(t,y,p) = (0,y_0,0)$.

Now, off the hypersurface $t=0$ in $typ$-space, this is equivalent to the system
$$
dy - p\ dt = \bigl((N{-}1)g(p)-tf(y)\bigr)\ dt + tg'(p)\ dp = 0.
$$
As long as $g(0)\not=0$ and $N>1$, this system has rank $2$ at the point $(t,y,p) = (0,y_0,0)$, so that there is a unique integral curve of the system passing through this point.  However, inspection shows that the curve is $(t,y,p) = (0,y_0,p)$ is an integral curve that passes through the point in question.  By uniqueness, it is the only one.

Thus, there is no integral curve of the kind that you would get from a solution to your problem.

I suspect that you have left out some hypotheses or not made a correct symmetry reduction of the system that you are trying to study.